# Inserting a bitmap image into Rich Edit Control

Tags: c++, bitmap, rich-text-editor

I am currently working on a project in which I need to use a pin pad device for an electronic signature capture.  When the electronic signature is captured, it is saved as a .bmp file.  When I take the same .bmp file and insert it into Rich Edit Control, it simply shows a filled in square box, instead of what the signature looks like.  When I open the .bmp in Microsoft Picture and Fax viewer, the .bmp displays properly... Meaning that I can visibly see the electronic signature that was captured from the pin pad device.

The operating system is "Windows Embedded", which is basically a stripped down version of Windows XP that is typically used by retailers.

Any opinion on how I can fix this would be great.  Note* It must be inserted via Rich Edit Control.  Use of any other program to insert the .bmp is not an option.

Comment: what the heck is Rick Edit Control? :)

Comment: anyway, try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/midas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this Codeguru article: [Insert any HBITMAP (Bitmap) in your RichEdit Control](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/controls/richedit/article.php/c5383/)